# External wsdl is not loading in magento but its loading in core php

Tags: php, api, wsdl, magento-1.6

This is working fine in core php, but not in magento.

```
$party_payment = new SoapClient('https://test.com/test.asmx?wsdl',array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0));
```

Last 2 days i am finding the solutions and reasons but no luck with it.

[Tried this link as well](http://www.magentogoreview.com/magento-api-soapclient-fatal-error-uncaught-soapfault-exception-wsdl-soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from~84)

Following error is coming

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://test.com/test.asmx?wsdl' : failed to load external entity &quot;https://test.com/test.asmx?wsdl&quot;
 in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Namespace\Module\Model\Module.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem before 2 Weeks with XAMPP. Perhaps you haven't enabled the openssl php-module.

You try to get the ressource over **https** this is only working when you have the openssl support activated.

You can try to access without SSL.

Comment: No problem :) the SOAP-ERROR is not really helpfull.